# Fatal Exception in android.widget.Button

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new to Java and Android. I'm trying to make an app that calculates a volume of a liquid in a cylinder, then return the result to a textView box. But now when I click the button to Calculate, it is crashing and I don't know what I'm missing. Everything compiles fine.

```
package com.somename.fuel.volume.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class CalculateCylinder extends Activity {

EditText length, width, height, depth;
TextView result;
Button calculate;
double firstNum, secNum, thirdNum, volume, area;
double liqVolume;
double radius;
double a, l, aSide,aTop,b,Arc,FluidSurfaceAreaTotal,r,d,v,h,fsal;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculate_cylinder);

    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCylCalc);

    length = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCylLength);
    height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCylHeight);
    depth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCylDepth);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonCylResult);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                calculate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            result.setText((CharSequence) result);
        }

        public TextView calculate() throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double firstNum = Double.valueOf(length.getText().toString());
            double secNum   = Double.valueOf(height.getText().toString());
            double thirdNum = Double.valueOf(depth.getText().toString());

            radius = (secNum/2);
            area = ((secNum*secNum)*3.14);
            //liqVolume = (firstNum) * (radius*radius)(acos(radius-depth/radius))
            // Cubic Volume

            v = aSide * l;
            // Fluid surface Area, Side
            aSide = (r*r)*(3.14 / 2 -Math.acos(1-h/r)) - (r-h)*Math.sqrt(h*(2*r-h));
            // Fluid Surface Area Top
            aTop = 2*Math.sqrt((r*r)-((r-h)*(r-h) * l));
            // Fluid Surface Area Bottom
            b = fsal*l;
            // Fluid Surface Area Total
            FluidSurfaceAreaTotal = 2*aSide+aTop+b;
            // Cylinder Radius
            r = d/2;
            // Cylinder Diameter
            d = 2*r;
            if (h <= r )
                // Fluid Side Arc Length
                fsal = 2*r*Math.acos((r-h)/r);

            else if (h > r)
                fsal = 2*r*(3.14-Math.acos((h-r)/r));
            return result;
            }


    });
}   

}
```

Here is a logcat:

```
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964): java.lang.ClassCastException:    android.widget.Button
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at   com.dbryant423.fuel.volume.calculator.CalculateCylinder$1.onClick(CalculateCylinder.java:55 )
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-18 05:24:38.893: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've been wracking my brains to try to figure out how to do the math on this, and I've not been able to find the answer to why it's crashing. I'm sure it's probably something simple that I've missed somewhere. If you need more information from the other files let me know, but this one seem the be the only one with the problem. I also know that there is unused variables that I've not removed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result.setText((CharSequence) result);
```

This line cause **Exception** because you are casting Android `View` class to `CharSequence` Class.

**Possible Solution:**

Change return type of your method   `public TextView calculate()` to

```
public String calculate()
```

Now in method `public String calculate()` **return String of result** `fsal`

And your button's `Click()` is something like,

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           String resultValue = "";
            try {
             resultValue =  calculate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            result.setText( resultValue);
        }
```

Comment: Ok, that didn't work. First, I need to return the value of "v" and set that value to the setText in the onClick method. When I change the type of calculate to String, I get a "Type mismatch, cannot convert from double to string.

Comment: Before return value from `calculate()` just change it to String from Double.

Comment: Well, I added this `String finalresult = Double.valueOf(v).toString();
    result.setText(finalresult);` to the end of calculate(). Now there are no more errors, and it returns a result, of 0.0 or NaN....so I think it's working, but my math is off somewhere...thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

```
result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonCylResult);
```

Are you casting properly? based on the naming, i would say that you are casting from a button to TextView. Try changing to,

```
result = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCylResult);
```

Comment: Well, I am casting to a button, it stands out better than a textView box, but it does not seem to make a difference when I change to Button, still gives me the 0.0 or NaN result. Though it shouldn't matter would it? I'm sending a string, and both a textView and a Button will accept that for the text.